# Call JavaScript polyfill for the HTML5 in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, placeholder

I am trying to show placeholders in IE9 and earlier versions. It works perfectly for all the pages but some of my pages have a very deep scripting. I wanted to ask that is it possible that I call the polyfill script mentioned here

http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/

specifically in my jquery function? I included this in header and it works perfect in most of the cases. But for few cases it doesnt work. I assume that if I can call this script specifically in those functions then it may work.

The file placeholders.min.js has jquery code so i do not know if i can call it or not?

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you download this to your server and then load it on every page that has form elements?

Comment: Looking at the “API” section in the documentation, I don’t see why you _shouldn’t_ be able to use it that way … so where’s the actual problem?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have included it on all the pages. Actually what looks to me is that it has some conflict with my script but if i call it manually into my function it will work...but i do not know what would be the code to call this code

Comment: @CBroe ok lets say if the input field has id "company", then how will i replace it in Placeholders.enable( [element] )??? something like Placeholders.enable($("#company"))? Kindly let me know please